# Mean of Sampleset and powered Sampleset

Tags: python, random, numpy, statistics

I am working on an [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) implementation wich is based on the assumption, that all source signals are independent. So I checked on the basic concepts of [Dependence vs. Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) and tried to show [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219234644/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64808.html) example on sample data

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
k =  1000
s = 10000
mn = 0
mnPow = 0
for i in arange(1,k):
    a = randn(s)
    a = a-mean(a)
    mn = mn + mean(a)
    mnPow = mnPow + mean(a**3)
print "Mean X: ", mn/k
print "Mean X^3: ", mnPow/k
```

But I couldn't produce the last step of this example E(X^3) = 0:

```
>> Mean X:  -1.11174580826e-18
>> Mean X^3:  -0.00125229267144
```

First value I would consider to be zero, but second value is too large, isn't it? Since I subtract the mean of `a`, I expected the mean of `a^3` to be zero as well. Does the problem lie in

1. the random number generator,
2. the precision of the numerical values
3. in my misunderstanding of the concepts of mean and expected value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample mean itself is a random variable. While its expected value here is zero, the particular realizations [will fluctuate around that expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution).

When I run the following many times:

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
k =  1000
s = 10000
mn = 0
mnPow = 0
for i in arange(k):
    a = randn(s)
    mn += mean(a)
    mnPow += mean(a**3)
print "Mean X: ", mn/k
print "Mean X^3: ", mnPow/k
```

I get numbers for both means that fluctuate around zero.

EDIT:

If you plot the density of this, the means look gaussian itself:
[image]

Note that I've removed `a = a-mean(a)` from your code since it's erroneous. With it, `mn` accumulates `mean(a - mean(a))` which is mathematically zero due to [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity):

```
E[x - E[x]] = E[x] - E[E[x]] = E[x] - E[x] = 0
```

The only reason it comes out as slightly non-zero is due to rounding errors.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. could you argue, why `a = a-mean(a)` is erroneous? I wanted to make sure, that `mean(a)` is zero. It is already from the model view and every distance from zero is just sample-size caused?

Comment: @MillaWell: I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Ah, now I got it! and `E((X-E(X))^3)=...=E(xE(x^2))-E(x^2E(x))`, which can be non-zero on sampledata!

Answer (score 1):

Probably just rounding error?

Have you tried computing the covariances and averaging those?